# Batch file does not follow through with launching program once given permission by the user account control

Tags: batch-file, launch

I have the following batch file:

```
for /f "delims=" %%x in (path.txt) do set path=%%x
set address=62.75.218.30:14567
start bf1942.exe
```

With `path.txt` file containing the path to the executable. Once I run the batch file I am prompted if I want to allow BF1942.exe to make changes to this computer (user account control). Once I select 'yes' nothing happens. Similarly when I launch BF1942.exe by double clicking on the icon I get the same prompt but the game launches after I give permission.

Edit: I did some investigation. When I moved the path.txt and the batch file into my Bf1942 folder and ran the batch file this worked. So the problem has something to do where the file is located.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the working directory ([do not change the system environment variable `path`](http://ss64.com/nt/path.html)) as follows:

```
for /f "delims=" %%x in (path.txt) do set "myPath=%%~x"
set "address=62.75.218.30:14567"
pushd "%myPath%"
start "" bf1942.exe
```

or

```
set "address=62.75.218.30:14567"
for /f "delims=" %%x in (path.txt) do (
    pushd "%%~x"
    start "" bf1942.exe
)
```

**Resources** (required reading):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%~x` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)

Comment: Should my myPath variable end with \BF1942.exe or just be a reference to the folder containing the exe file?

Comment: _With path.txt file containing the path to the executable_. Works for **path to the executable** (e.g. `c:\Bf1942` or  `c:\Bf1942\ `). If contains **the executable full path** (e.g. `c:\Bf1942\bf1942.exe`), then use `pushd "%%~dpx"`... Read the _Command Line arguments (Parameters)_ reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can either move your batch file to the same folder as the executable or specify the full path to the executable in the batch file.

For example:

```
start c:\Bf1942\bf1942.exe
```

Also, you shouldn't use `path` as a variable name. There is a system environment variable named `path` and your batch is overwriting it. Change yours to `myPath` or something else.